# Software for recommending papers -- does this exist?

Tags: research-process, software

I spend a lot of time on google scholar making sure I haven't missed relevant literature. Usually this means scrolling through the "cited by" list one by one for at least 5-10 major papers on the topic.

It occurs to me that this could be done better and faster by a computer. Has anyone made software that does something like the following?

**Input**: A collection of papers

**Output**: Some papers similar to the input papers, based on citations or semantic analysis

I have in mind something like the "related papers" link on google scholar, but accepting more than one paper as input.

Comment: Mendeley tries this.

Comment: Thanks! This helps. It sounds like they have the methods I already use, plus Mendeley suggest (which I'll now try out). It's really good to learn about this.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at https://www.meta.org/ - you can create research interests and the search engine then suggests relevant articles for you (or tries to), based on machine learning.